# tikz state initial with vertical orientation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I change the orientation of the start arrow to come from the top instead of coming from the left as it is its default behavior. Can anyone advice using as base the TikZ State Machine example:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                        semithick]
      \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

      \node[initial,state] (A)                    {$q_a$};
      \node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$q_b$};
      \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$q_d$};
      \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$q_c$};
      \node[state]         (E) [below of=D]       {$q_e$};

      \path (A) edge              node {0,1,L} (B)
                edge              node {1,1,R} (C)
            (B) edge [loop above] node {1,1,L} (B)
                edge              node {0,1,L} (C)
            (C) edge              node {0,1,L} (D)
                edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (E)
            (D) edge [loop below] node {1,1,R} (D)
                edge              node {0,1,R} (A)
            (E) edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Use `initial above` instead of `initial`. This is explained in section "24.3
Initial and Accepting States" of the manual.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change the orientation of the `initial` state by using `initial above` (or `initial below`, `initial left` or `initial right`).